# Errors while building signature build with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

While using ProGuard, I am getting io warnings and errors. I have set

```
minifyEnabled = "true" -- I don't want this to be set to false.
```

How to resolve io errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Proguard rules for the libraries you are using. From the errors I think you need rules for Realm and Gson. Here is it

```
# Proguard Configuration for Realm (http://realm.io)
# For detailed discussion see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/realm-java/umqKCc50JGU
# Additionally you need to keep your Realm Model classes as well
# For example:
-keep class com.yourapppackagetomodelclass.realm.** { *; }
-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class *
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

PS: Instead of `com.yourapppackagetomodelclass.realm` use your package where `RealmObject` classes are stores

**UPDATE**
For IBM warnings you can check for their proguard rules online and if not available then use like this

```
-keepclassmembers com.ibm.mce.sdk.adm.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers ibm.mce.sdk.plugin.inapp.** { *; }
```

Comment: For that you need to mention which library you are using OR have look on updated answer.

Comment: @user45678 If it is MCE SDK library you can also have a look over here https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/356328/what-is-the-recommended-proguard-configuration-for-1.html